# References error in Python

Tags: python, reference

The problem comes from the `state` variable (in args). It is modified in my code (after the `new_state` modifications). However, I've read that using `list()` could prevent this kind of problem (it looks like `state` and `new_state` have the same reference).

To sum up, if I display the value of state at the beginning of the function, and just before the return, the values are different (and I obviously don't want to change the value of this variable !). How can I solve this problem ?

```
def successor(self, state, numberClients, numberDepots, Q, dist_table):         
    succ_list = list() 
    for i in range(0, len(state)): 
        for j in range(0, len(state[i])): 
           switchIndex = 0 
           while switchIndex < length: 
              permutationIndex = 0 
              while permutationIndex < len(state[switchIndex]):                     
                  new_state = list(state) 
                  temp = new_state[switchIndex][permutationIndex] 
                  new_state[switchIndex][permutationIndex] = new_state[i][j] 
                  new_state[i][j] = temp 
                  if checkConst(new_state): # accept only in some cases (we don't care here)
                      succ_list.append(('act', new_state))             
                  permutationIndex += 1 
           switchIndex += 1 
    return succ_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `state` is a list of lists?

When you do `new_state = list(state)`, you are copying the outer list, but the references inside the copy still point to the same inner lists.

Try this:

```
new_state = [list(e) for e in state]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have found the solution yourself. The references in the call: `list(...)` are copied to the new list. So essentially, it is not a deep copy but a shallow copy. The following code explains it.

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a=map(lambda x:A(), range(5))
>>> a
[<__main__.A instance at 0x1018d11b8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x1018f17a0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x101868950>, <__main__.A instance at 0x1018687a0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x101868830>]
>>> b=list(a)
>>> b
[<__main__.A instance at 0x1018d11b8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x1018f17a0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x101868950>, <__main__.A instance at 0x1018687a0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x101868830>]
>>> b[0].v=23
>>> a
[<__main__.A instance at 0x1018d11b8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x1018f17a0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x101868950>, <__main__.A instance at 0x1018687a0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x101868830>]
>>> a[0]
<__main__.A instance at 0x1018d11b8>
>>> a[0].v
23
```

Also, in order to prevent the problem, you can use:-

```
import copy
```

And, then, use `new_state = copy.deepcopy(state)` in your code instead of `new_state = list(state)`.

The following code explains this:-

```
>>> import copy
>>> copy.deepcopy
<function deepcopy at 0x1004d71b8>


>>> a=map(lambda x:A(), range(5))
>>> b=copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b[0].v=23
>>> a[0].v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'v'
```

Comment: Ok deepcopy will do the trick, thanks guys ! It's a list of lists yeah.